# pl/sql loop records select oracle plsql

Tags: for-loop, plsql, oracle11g, conditional-statements, procedure

I have a select statement that I am trying to loop over and increment a variable based on the condition of the select statement, then return the variable as an `out` so I can do something with it in some front end code.  I am using oracle 11g and I am seeing a few ways I can do this... but I am not sure which is the best way.  I have some of what I am trying to do below, but again stopped because of confusion.

First I am setting my proc and 'in variable'

```
PROCEDURE SEEKER (pMonkeyID IN Number, vMarkCounter OUT Number)
AS
BEGIN

CURSOR seeker_cur IS
    Select Mokney_approved, Monkey_vaulted 
    from MonkeyBookApps 
    where MonkeyID = pMonkeyID
    and Monkey_doc_type = 'BANANA' 
    order by docu_approv_timestamp,monkey_doc_type,monkey_doc_approved desc

OPEN seeker_cur;

begin

   OPEN Seeker_cur;
   vMarkCounter := 0;
```

Here is the part I am not sure about. Should I loop and then exit if the condition is not met or should I do an if statement and somehow determine if there is a record that could be greater than one?  If so how would that work? Is there a benefit to doing one way over the other? So... I am going to sudo-code what I am trying to do (below):

```
FOR (however many records) in Seeker_cur
IF seeker_cur (not found) or (returns no records)

EXIT or (break for loop);
ELSE
LOOP

vMarkCounter := vMarkCounter + 1;

EXIT WHEN seeker_cur is out of records (somehow)
END IF;
END LOOP;

END; 
END SEEKER;
```

I am sure there are a few ways to do this. What ways would you suggest?

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using COUNT() here? Why loop at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why dont you use implicit cursor , it will open and close itself:

```
DECLARE

CURSOR seeker_cur IS
    Select Mokney_approved, Monkey_vaulted 
    from MonkeyBookApps 
    where MonkeyID = pMonkeyID
    and Monkey_doc_type = 'BANANA' 
    order by docu_approv_timestamp,monkey_doc_type,monkey_doc_approved desc;

  vMarkCounter number:=0;

BEGIN

  FOR i IN seeker_cur 
  LOOP
    vMarkCounter := vMarkCounter+1;
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line(vMarkCounter);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the solution your problem might be as simple as this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO   l_some_local_variable
FROM   monkey_book_apps 
WHERE  monkey_id = p_monkey_id
   AND monkey_doc_type = 'BANANA';

RETURN l_some_local_variable;
```

Avoiding PL/SQL loops and using the simplest SQL possible is (almost always) the most efficient way. [Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com) calls the row-by-row execution of LOOPs "slow-by-slow".